# Filtering a json and saving it to another file if it contains a certain word in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Clemens",
        "last_name": "Parramore",
        "email": "cparramore0@google.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "ip_address": "223.150.139.137"
    },
    {
        "id": 1000,
        "first_name": "Theodore",
        "last_name": "Agostini",
        "email": "tagostinirr@archive.org",
        "gender": "Male",
        "ip_address": "6.131.228.196"
    }
]
```

And I am trying to filter it so that if it contains certain characters it is saved in a new json. My method does not give results, the new file contains all the information from the original json:

```
f = open('./data/data.json','r')
data = json.load(f)    
fj = open('new.json', 'w')
for line in str(data).split('{'):
    if "google" in line:
        print(line, end="\n")
        fj.write(line)
```

However in the print I do get what I want. I know the method is wrong, can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Your code prints to stdout and writes to the file as expected. I tried with a string that actually occurs in the data you posted (since `"google"` doesn't.

Comment: Do note that your current approach doesn't actually process the json file as json, it processes it as a string -- and as a result, the output isn't valid json. Which fields are you interested in checking, just whether the `email` contains `"google"`?

Comment: Yes, I just one that ones that contains certain string, but i don,t know how to do it with proccess it like a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. Please leave a comment if you need something more specific.

```
import json

to_be_saved = []
with open("data/data.json") as raw_data:
  data = json.load(raw_data)
  for entry in data:
    if "google" in entry["email"]:
      to_be_saved.append(entry)

    # Alternatively, if you only want to check the email domain,
    # use this instead of the lines above:

    # if "google" in entry["email"].split("@")[1]:
    #   to_be_saved.append(entry)

# print(to_be_saved)

with open("result.json", "w") as output_data:
  output_data.write(json.dumps(to_be_saved, indent=2))
```

results.json file after running this script:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Clemens",
    "last_name": "Parramore",
    "email": "cparramore0@google.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "ip_address": "223.150.139.137"
  }
]
```

Comment: this method also keeps the mail with the value `abcgoogle123@def.org` within the new file @MickiTicki

Comment: Added commented code in case the OP wants to filter on email domain

Comment: Oh It,s true. So cool. Thanks @HubertGrzeskowiak

Comment: right, added after warning about the case :) @MickiTicki

Answer (score 2):

You can use `literal_eval` function of `ast` in order to get raw data write to another file by using `json.dumps` in order to make the result pretty, after filtering out the mail values containing `google` library such as

```
import json
import ast

elm=[]
with open('data.json') as f, open('new.json', 'w') as f_out:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        val = data[i]['email'].split('@')[1]
        if val[:val.find('.')]=='google': -- only mail addresses with "@google." syntax is kept within the result file,
                                          -- "google543@abc.com" is not kept as an example.
            elm.append(data[i])
    f_out.write(json.dumps(elm, indent=4))
```

Comment: Also works, but I don´t understand the method

Comment: can you tell me what you did not understand ? @MickiTicki

Comment: The bucle part.

Comment: @MickiTicki  it looks for evey member `data[i]` (where i=0,1,..) of the given dict, and grabs the mails only with the values of  `....@google.<the rest>`

Comment: Okey, I,m reading about the ast module. Know I got it. Thanks for the answer :D